# Create permanent video meeting link in Microsoft Teams

Tags: video, office-365, outlook, microsoft-teams

I have recently started using Microsoft Teams for videoconferencing, since my organization is moving to it as its primary collaboration platform within our Office 365 application suite.

I schedule many videoconferences with people outside my organization (some of them repeated) and the way I do it now is to create a Teams meeting link from my Outlook invitation and then send this to the meeting invitees. I would prefer to create a permanent link that I can always give to people, for example, in an email message, without having to generate a new Teams meeting each time in Outlook.

I considered simply reusing the same link from a previous meeting for subsequent meetings, but it seems that each Teams meeting creates its own space in Teams. So, it seems that people I meet with later would be able to see the names of those whom I met with earlier using the same link, as well as any conversations I might have had with them. So, I don't think this is what I want--I want a  link that gives meeting attendees access to only the present, live meeting, with no access to past exchanges using the same link. This is important to respect the privacy of each meeting.

Does Microsoft Teams have a feature to generate a permanent link for videoconferences that preserves the privacy of attendees across different meetings using that same link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of April 2020, there is no such feature. However, it has been requested and interested users can vote to bring it to Microsoft's attention and raise their priority of treating it: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/39869779-create-permanent-video-meeting-link-in-microsoft-t. (Microsoft does actively monitor and act upon the votes on Uservoice.)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting up your meetings as reoccurring in Teams? This option uses the same meeting number for a specific meeting. I have several reoccurring monthly and weekly meetings and with this option I get to use the same meeting number for each specific meeting.

Comment: That is not at all the same thing. I have recurring meetings in Team when I need them, but I am asking for a link that I can give anyone anytime, yet will not retain the history of previous conversations. A recurring meeting retains conversation history, so that does not serve this particular need.

Answer (score -2):

Not understanding why, you don't want to "generate a new Teams meeting each time in Outlook."
So, this might miss the mark, but Outlook has a workflow for this: Choosing "reply with meeting" in Outlook would send an Outlook/Teams meeting back to the sender. This will require 2 clicks ("Reply with Meeting" and "Teams Meeting" buttons) this would send a unique meeting id every time keeping your different meetings separate and private.